How to set and receive arguments to custom visual studio project command
I have created a custom command for the visual studio project and the command is visible on the project right-click. I wanted to pass some arguments like project folder path to the command EventArgs. Is it possible to specify arguments to the command.
Here is the command Execution method.
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
    string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Inside {0}.MenuItemCallback()", GetType().FullName);
    string title = "Evaluate Project Command";

    // Show a message box to prove we were here
    VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
                                    package,
                                    message,
                                    title,
                                    OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                                    OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                                    OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
}

I want to get the Project file path from the command EventArgs or is there any way to do it?

If you take a look at the EventArgs reference document, you will see it doesn't have the information you need, DTE should be the correct way, take a look at my answer. :)

The EventArgs in the method signature for the command execution does not typically contain this data directly. However, you can retrieve the project details by accessing the DTE object, which represents the development environment itself.
Take a look at this example:
https://github.com/NDiiong/DevAssist/blob/3a90dbbbd42c57dd74749f01e26ba30aeac68732/src/Commands/OpenBinFolderCommand.cs#L18

In order to support parameters when invoking your command (for example, invoking the File.OpenFile) command from the Command Window and supplying a path or filename; you'll need to create an OleMenuCommand rather than a MenuCommand. Additionally, you will need to set the ParametersDescription property on your OleMenuCommand For example:
private MultiParamCommand(AsyncPackage package, OleMenuCommandService commandService)
{
    this.package = package ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));
    commandService = commandService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandService));

    var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
    var menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(this.Execute, menuCommandID);
    menuItem.ParametersDescription = "arguments";
    menuItem.BeforeQueryStatus += BeforeQueryStatus; 
    commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
}

Additionally, the command itself must be defined in your .VSCT with the AllowParams command flag. For example:
<Buttons>
  <Button guid="guidAllowParamsPackageCmdSet" id="MultiParamCommandId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidAllowParamsPackageCmdSet" id="AllowParamsMenuGroup" />
    <CommandFlag>AllowParams</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>MultiParamCommand</ButtonText>
      <CanonicalName>MultiParamCommand</CanonicalName>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
</Buttons>

This will allow you to invoke the command from the command tool window, and specify arguments. Note, the arguments will be passed into your commands Execute method via the EventArgs parameter. But you'll need to cast this to a OleMenuCmdEventArgs to access it. For example:
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
    
    OleMenuCmdEventArgs eventArgs = (OleMenuCmdEventArgs)e;
    string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Arguments passed to MultiParamCommand: {0}", eventArgs.InValue);
    string title = "MultiParamCommand";

    // Show a message box to prove we were here
    VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
        this.package,
        message,
        title,
        OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
        OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
        OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
}

Sincerely,

Thanks for the suggestion, how do you set the file path to the command arguments, i think the parameter description is like a 'key'. When i right click on the project node how do i set the project folder path to the arguments?

AllowParams is really only useful if you want to support invoking the command from the command tool window. If you are simply wanting to retrieve the filename of the item you right clicked on, to invoke your context menu, you don't need AllowParams. Just use the IVsMonitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection, and IVSProject.GetMkDocument to retrieve the filename of the solution item that you clicked on:
    private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        IVsMultiItemSelect vsMIS = null;
        uint itemID = VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL;
        IntPtr hierPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr selConPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IVsProject vsProject = null;

        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        IVsMonitorSelection monitorSelection = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection)) as IVsMonitorSelection;
        Assumes.Present(monitorSelection);

        try
        {
            ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierPtr, out itemID, out vsMIS, out selConPtr));
            vsProject = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(hierPtr) as IVsProject;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (hierPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.Release(hierPtr);
            }
            if (selConPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.Release(selConPtr);
            }
        }

        string documentMoniker;
        vsProject.GetMkDocument(itemID, out documentMoniker);

        string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "filename of selected item: {0}", documentMoniker);
        string title = "Demo Package";
        VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(this.package, message, title, OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO, OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK, OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);

}

